# I was migrating from log4j.xml to log4j2.xml .How do I set <param name="Append" value="true" /> in RollingAppender in log4j2.xml

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

```
    <appender name="FILE" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
                <param name="File" value="${logserver.log.path}logServer.log" />
                **<param name="Append" value="true" />**
                <param name="MaxFileSize" value="10MB" />
                <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="10" />
                <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
                    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="[%t] %d{MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss.SSS} %p :%m%n" />
                </layout>
            </appender>

I was migrating from log4j.xml to log4j2.xml .How do I set <param name="Append" value="true" /> in RollingAppender in log4j2.xml

This are the changes I've done:
<RollingFile name="FILE" fileName="${logserver.log.path}logServer.log" append="true">
      <PatternLayout>
        <Pattern>[%t] %d{MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss.SSS} %p :%m%n</Pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
      <Policies>
        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB"/>
      </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="10"/>
    </RollingFile>
```

Will append=true work???for the same1

currently i am upgrading log4j version from 1.x to log4j2.x , to do that i need to configure log4j2.xml, how to convert the below mentioned log4j.xml file to log4j2.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your log4j.xml doesn't roll over based on time, only on size.

```
<RollingFile name="FILE" filePattern="${logserver.log.path}logServer-%i.log" append="true">
  <PatternLayout>
    <Pattern>[%t] %d{MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss.SSS} %p :%m%n</Pattern>
  </PatternLayout>
  <Policies>
    <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="10 MB"/>
  </Policies>
  <DirectWriteRolloverStrategy maxFiles="10"/>
 </RollingFile>
```

This will do the same as yours. It uses the DirectWriteRolloverStrategy to write directly to each of the files to be rolled and only keep a max of 10 files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below format.

```
 <!-- Rolling File Appender -->
    <RollingFile name="RollingFile">
      <FileName>C:/log/mylog.log</FileName>
      <FilePattern>C:/log/time-based-logs/%d{yyyy-MM-dd-hh-mm}.log.zip</FilePattern>
      <PatternLayout>
        <Pattern>%d{yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss a} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</Pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
      <Policies>
        <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="2" modulate="true" />
      </Policies>
      <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="5" />
    </RollingFile>
```

To get more details visit https://www.boraji.com/log4j-2-rollingfileappender-example#rolling-based-on-Date-and-Time

Comment: There is no probation to set  **<param name="Append" value="true" />** in logj2.xml?